# Given that $f(x) = 1 - 3/(x+2) + 3/(x+2)$ while $x ≠- 2$, show that $f(x) = (x^2 + x + 1)/(x+2)^2$

Tags: quadratics, factoring

What type of problem is this and what are the first step(s) needed to tackle it?

---

> Given that:
>   $$f(x) = 1-\frac{3}{x + 2}+\frac{3}{(x  +2)^2}, \quad \text{with }x ≠ -2$$
>   Show that:
>   $$f(x) = \frac{x^2 + x +1}{(x + 2)^2}$$

It's fairly basic, clearly, but from my attempts so far it appears that finding common denominators doesn't take you from the first form to the second.

Should something be factorised?

Comment: I believe you just have to check your math again.

Comment: The condition should be $x\ne-2$.

Comment: For the record, the example I was given _definitely_ states $x ≠ 2$, but the correction made here of course makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of factorization, just evaluate the sum
$$1-\frac{3}{x + 2}+\frac{3}{(x  +2)^2}=\frac{(x  +2)^2-3(x  +2)+3}{(x  +2)^2}.$$
What do you obtain after expanding the numerator?

Comment: Ah - the function syntax has no impact (except to distract me into confusion with the basics) - that's great to confirm, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x) = 1-\frac{3}{x + 2}+\frac{3}{(x  +2)^2}; x ≠ 2$$

$$\implies f(x) = \frac{(x+2)^2}{(x+2)^2}-\frac{3(x+2)}{(x + 2)^2}+\frac{3}{(x  +2)^2}$$

$$\implies f(x) = \frac{(x+2)^2-3(x+2)+3}{(x+2)^2}$$

Just expand and then add up the values in the numerator...